# Best way to make view counter for topic / post

Tags: php, counter

I'm confusing how to make the view counter for topic with my forum with PHP.

The regular way is when the topic take hit , topic_views = topic_views + 1.

But the spammer can spam views to get higher rank this way.

so. what's the best option to make view counter but avoid the spammer ?

Answer (score 0):

Just throw in a simple IP check, so one IP can't bump a count more than once. (or not to often)

Answer (score 0):

Probably want to store a `views` table along with the user IP.  Only increment the topic view counter if that IP hasn't viewed it before.  You can also store either a table or array of spam IP's that you can include on the check as well.

Comment: with many country, they're not use static IP. IP change everyday. and Store IP i think will take lots of resources?